# Inverse of an $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I'm curious to know the matrix form of the inverse of an $n\times n$ matrix. Also, how many operations will be needed to compute it?

Comment: I'd assume the only closed form expression in general would be the one using the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Git Gud said, a closed form would be $$A_{ij}=\frac{(\textrm{adj } A)_{ij}}{\det A}$$
Using the notation $A_{ij}$ for the element at the i-th row and j-th column of $A$.

About the quantity of operations, there is several algorithms for computing $A^{-1}$, and generally they cost $O(n^3)$ operations.

Answer (score 1):

As Integral said, there are many algorithms available for computing matrix inverses. A few of them are described on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Except for very small matrices (of size 2 or 3) encountered in linear algebra homework assignments, no-one would ever compute a matrix inverse using the adjugate/determinant formula. It's complexity is far worse than $O(n^3)$.